# How To Deploy Multiple Different Mobile Apps Inside One Mobile App?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I would like to have multiple different iOS mobile apps inside one master iOS Mobile App.

Once the user login to the master app, they will have a list of the mobile apps, and each individual mobile app will be independently developed by different team and updated/deployed individually. There is only on master app that user will  ever need to download to their device.

I know lot of big gaming companies are doing it, just not sure how they did it.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I know Roblox and other gaming companies are doing it. Do you have an idea how can they make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apps you're talking about(like Roblox) doesn't have any real subapps. It only looks like this, but technically all those apps are just the app screens.
You can split your app code into modules, each representing an "app", and each team will only have access and work on it's own.

If you app will have a lot of resources, you can use [On-Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html). So it'll look like you're downloading an app. But you can only use this feature for things like images, videos, textures, but not the code itself - that's the main reason why you won't be able to deploy subapps separately. You'll have to deploy the master app when any of the apps is updated.

Comment: thank you for your answer, Roblox have all the independent developers use their Roblox studio to submit the app. I wonder what kind of framework are they using?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe each subapp gets built to a separate app for easy testing, but when publishing to the app store they're making a superapp out of them all. I haven't heard of framework doing so, but it's easy to setup - just create a module for each app, in "debug app" you'll run your own module, and in the superapp you'll combine all the modules.

Answer (score 2):

If all the sub apps were under 10MB you could use appClips to do this.

The "master" app can host a list of universal links to registered appClips.

This would then download each app as the user interacts with them in the master app.

The apple device will unload unused appClips over time, but with the master app won't be in danger of this as it would be a full App.

Users could then either open them from the master app permanently or open them through the App Library

Comment: Thank you @MindBlower3, do you have any reference documents I can read for more details.

Comment: Haha not that i know of, this was just something i came up with as a solution. 
There is plenty of documentation of how to build an appClip and upload them to the app store (your child apps still need to submit it as part of a package) 
In regards to having them in your master app, that a matter of you building attractive cells to advertise each and then use universal links to open the child

Comment: Thank you @MindBlower3

Comment: app clips are pretty limited, you can check out more in to official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/choosing_the_right_functionality_for_your_app_clip?language=objc. So depending on how complex your application should be, it may or may not work